# Android: How to record video using android.hardware.camera2 and MediaRecorder

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I want to make video recording using `android.hardware.camera2`. I have googled but not get any proper tutorial regarding this. There are some tutorial available for `camera preview` base on [Camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) which is now deprecated. Can anyone help me with latest sample code just for `recording video` with its `preview` which can be saved into `sd card`. I have just check [GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) and  [Google camera2Video example](https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Video/index.html) also but I need any simple solution which I can integrated into my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> just for recording video with its preview which can be saved into sd
>   card

If thats all you want you can simply use:

```
static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;

Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
}
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html)

---

If you want to implement that yourself with the help of camera2. I would suggest to have a look at the sourcecode of [googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

Espacially at [Camera2BasicFragment.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually I want to capture video with preview on tap and hold button. Can you please guide me regarding that means how can I do this.

Comment: @SakibSyed Have you checked https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic ? I would start there since it shows everyhing you will need . If you run into a problem I would suggest you to create a new question including the code you wrote so far

Comment: Ok me check first first

Comment: @ IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII Thanks you for continuously reply but  I have gone through https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video to `record video with preview` but its code has some issue means not working properly. Can you please guide me how to record video using `camera2` or any tutorial or sample code so that I can implement into my project.

Comment: Camera2Video is about as simple as it's going to get. You'd probably do better trying to figure out why it's not working for you. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @SakibSyed you should really: 1)create a new question 2) show the code you wrote so far 3) and describe whats not working / the errors you get! No one here will guide you step by step on what you need to do!

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII I was testing this in emulator which did't work yesterday but today when I run into device it works fine. Means your solution is working properly. So I have to make sure that I have to run this code only device otherwise it will show erro. Thanks for quick response and help me brother..

Answer (score 2):

Look at this open-source project

[WesleyElliott/Camera2-Video](https://github.com/WesleyElliott/Camera2-Video?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4433)

There is working code, instead of sample by google